# Avoid "Windows protected your PC" message for a authenticode cert signed install4j installer

Tags: windows-10, install4j, sign, authenticode

Any clue how to avoid my installer triggering the **Windows protected your PC** message upon launch?  I thought signing with Authenticode was supposed to fix this but alas not.

Whereas the unsigned installer described publisher as unknown, the signed copy lists our company as publisher and the exe definitely is signed as I can see the appropriate cert attached.

My problem is that I still the the "Don't run" protection dialog.

Please let me know if you have a link to how to properly register my cert to avoid this security check all together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the Windows Smartscreen filter. It will stop reporting your certificate once it has been downloaded a number of times from different IP addresses.

The only way around this is an EV certificate which requires a hardware dongle.

Comment: oh that's unfortunate.  I had thought signing would clear this.  So there's no way to ensure my customers don't hit this problem.  that's unfortunate.

Comment: "after it has been downloaded a number of times"... does anyone know how many?